# Unable to delete a file created by FileHelper assembly

Tags: c#, file, process, filehelpers

I am fetching details from db and writing them on a file using FileHelper, attach the file as part of an email and try to delete the file after mail is sent.

```
 var engine = new FileHelperEngine<DataModel>();

 engine.WriteFile(filePath, data);

 //After Mail is sent, deleting the file.
 if (File.Exists(filePath))
 {                           
   File.Delete(filePath); //Error is thrown here
 }
```

> Exception : The process cannot access the file '..//somefilepath'
>   because it is being used by another process.

I have to delete these files as soon as the mail is sent , letting them reside on server will consume space in the server.

How to delete these files when held by another process?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your response .
The issue was occurring because of Attachment instance that was holding the file and was not letting me delete the file.

```
MailMessage mailobj= new MailMessage();
Attachment data = new Attachment(filePath);
mailobj.Attachments.Add(data);

//after sending mail, i disposed the data
 data.Dispose();
```

Comment: You cannot delete a file that is in use. Windows won't allow it. I would suggest you try it multiple times with a little delay before each new try.

Comment: _After mail is sent_ That raises a red flag. Did you add that file as an allegate and are you using the _using statement_ around that mail sent procedure? Please show the code that send the mail.

Comment: Make sure you dispose of everything properly.  I suspect here that your code is not disposing all disposable objects.  Whilst you dispose of 'data' you already add that to a collection and once you ask the server object to send the mail, it will open that file, not the attachment object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not coming from the code in the question. The `WriteFile()` function opens, writes, and closes the file automatically, so the file does not stay in use. The mail client is the culprit that is still using the file when you try to delete it. Make sure it finishes and releases the file before you try to delete it. If you need help with that, edit your question and add the code for sending the mail.

Note: some mail clients can automatically delete the files after they successfully send it. Check if your mail client has that feature and enable it, so you don't need to delete the file by yourself.

Also some mail clients accept memory streams. If your mail client accepts memory streams, you may consider saving your data to a `MemoryStream` and pass it to the mail client instead of a file. This way you don't need to worry about creating and deleting the file.

Comment: You were right . It wasn't FileHelper's WriteLine(). I had an Attachment instance as part of sending the mail,which was holding the file.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so that others know without having to delve into the comments

Answer (score 2):

If there is another process (e.g. local email client) accessing/linking the file, you would have to close this process before File.Delete. Perhaps instead of using the file directly, you may try MemoryStream to copy the file into memory which you can dispose, that to ensure the file is not used by another process then you can do File.Delete.